# Understanding how Weighted overlay tool works

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, weighted-overlay

After watching videos and reading the documentation, I just can't wrap my head around the weighted overlay tool.

I need to create an in-depth go-no go zone for a school project. I have got several rasters that indicate a no-go zone and 1 or 2 that indicate a "maybe" zone. However these have no other values, so they are either a 1 or a 2. It is crucial however that several 1's on the same location can be a 2.

I am looking for a way to use the weighted overlay tool for this, so that in a later stage I can use the least cost path analysis on it as well. I am using ArcGIS Pro for this.

What I have done so far is the following:

- taken the rasters that are a no-go zone and reclassified them to 1.
- The maybe-zones are reclassified to 2.
- The rasters don't have a different value, no ranking within themselves other than "all of this raster is 1" or " all of this raster is 2".
- After running these rasters through the weight overlay tool, it comes back with an error. I haven't found the same situation online.
- The error is: error 010092: Invalid output extent

I want the weight overlay to be 1-10, 10 being the most favorable (at this moment, NoData would be 10, as there is no raster that would be a restriction)

Comment: Your problem is "There is also NoData in these rasters which would be the most favorable locations" NoData are (as the name imply) an absence of data and as such can't be used in calculation (it will return no data or skip the value depending on your setting). you need to reclass your raster to give the most favorable locations an adequate value...

Comment: I have fixed the NoData with another reclassify, so the values in the rasters are now 0, 1 or 2. In the weighted overlay I put 10 "ranks" but when I let it run I get an error (I've put it in the original post). I've searched the web but the errors that I find don't compare to my situation.